# Pull SubString (in Array) from Cell and Parse into Column

Tags: excel, vba, split, substring

I have a list of of strings that I want to parse from larger strings, so for example, in:

"Cabinet; Door ; Birch ; Stained" ---> [This is a part Nomenclature. There may or may not be delimiters]-

I want to run through a list of parts and parse out certain strings, as in an array as such:

D1: Door

D2: Shelf

D3: Base
;

Etc, Etc--- And put it in to a new column. So this would happen:

Cabinet, Door, Birch, Stained ----> Door (In new column)

Cabinet, Shelf, Birch, Stained ----> Shelf (In same column as above)

Cabinet, Base, Birch, Stained ----> Base (in same column as above)

Basically this is to parse and more easily assign common taxonomy - It runs through a cell, looks for a Value in that Array (D1:D10, whatever) - and then SPLITs it off.

Thanks!

Comment: Will it ever need to match two or more values from the array?

Comment: It's possible, but unlikely (a terrible answer, I know.) It's not necessarily problematic to return the first string it hits that's in the array; I suspect it won't be a large enough problem that can't be tacked one by one. - So if it does say like "Cabinet, Shelf Base, Birch, Stained" it's okay to return "Shelf" instead of "base" , "shelf"

Comment: What does "There may or may not be delimiters" mean? Does that mean there could be something like "Cabinet Shelf Base Birch Stained" with just spaces?  If that is the case, how would you know whether two of those words belonged together in the same 'value', like "Shelf Base"?

Comment: Just in that we will design the array of values to parse by such as that that isn't the case- is the "value" is "Shelf Base", we're happy enough to get either "Shelf" or "base- " if it returns the first value it finds in the string, totally okay with that

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$10;MATCH(1;1*ISNUMBER(FIND($D$1:$D$10;G1));0))
```

Cell value in G1

This is an array formula so you need Ctrl Shift Enter to enter it.

Copy the formula down for all the others

Depending on your Regional Settings you may need to replace ";"  by ","

Comment: Yes- that's exactly right. Thank you so much - that saves a ton of time. I hadn't thought about nesting an isnumber. You are awesome! thank you!